# Android Volley: Cannot resolve Constructor jsonobjectrequest

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to use volley to fetch JSON and parse. But android studio says cannot resolve constructor jsonobjetrequest. I am not able to understand what is the mistake. The following is the code.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try{
                            JSONArray routes = response.getJSONArray("routes");
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Your project uses Google's volley or mcxiaoke's volley?

Comment: I am developing using android SDK.  There imports like import com.android.volley.Request; being used.

Comment: Try one of the two options: remove `Request.Method.GET`, or remove `null`

Comment: yeh that worked. How is that it worked.

Comment: You can press Ctrl-B at `JsonObjectRequest` to view its definition

Comment: thank you. I will check and understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your project uses mcxiaoke's volley, in which there are two following constructors:

```
public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody,
                             Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener,
                errorListener);
    }

public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
    }
```

So if you pass `null`, there is no way for the class to know which constructor to be used.

As commented, you can either remove `Request.Method.GET`, or remove `null`, or casting such as `(String)null` or `(JSONObject)null`.

P/S: if your project uses Google's official volley, the constructor in your question is correct.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. Its more clear now. Because i copied from "http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800". How to know its mcxiaoke's or googles. Which is recommended

Comment: For mcxiaoke: you will find in `build.gradle` file the line such as `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'`

Comment: If you want google's volley, read from here http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: why android uses mcxiaoke as default. If i want to change to google how to do it

Comment: No, it's not default. Just because you copied from a project which used that library. If want to change to google's one, pls read Google's documentation as my above link