# Android Volley ambiguous reference to JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, android-volley

i'm trying to use simple `Volley` JsonObjectRequest fro web service but i get this error:

```
 error: reference to JsonObjectRequest is ambiguous, both constructor JsonObjectRequest(int,String,String,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) in JsonObjectRequest and constructor JsonObjectRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) in JsonObjectRequest match
```

[image]

i'm install volley from `Gradle` and this is my simple code which i'm using in project.

```
public class Simple_JsonRequest extends Activity {
    private TextView mTvResult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act__json_request);
        mTvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        Button btnJsonRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_json_request);
        btnJsonRequest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();
                JsonObjectRequest myReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                                                        "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two",
                                                        null,
                   createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                   createMyReqErrorListener());
                queue.add(myReq);
            }
        });
    }


    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    mTvResult.setText(response.getString("one"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    mTvResult.setText("Parse error");
                }
            }
        };
    }
    private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mTvResult.setText(error.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: How about you replace the `null` which is the 3rd argument, with something more specific and then try ?

Comment: @SharpEdge Thanks sir, problem solved, please post new reply and let me to accept and upvote that

Comment: I've posted my comment as answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428462/android-volley-cannot-resolve-constructor-jsonobjectrequest/33428758#33428758 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you replace the `null` which is the 3rd argument, with something more specific and then try ?

Answer (score 0):

Because JsonObjectRequest have two constructors,
one is 
`JsonObjectRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener)`
and another is 
`JsonObjectRequest(int,String,String,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener)`,so if you set the third parameter to null,the compiler won't know which constructor you want to use,so such an error occurred.

To solve your problem,you just can replace your third parameter to `new JSONObject()` or `""`.

Comment: thatnks sir, problem not solved, i get an same error